# ChromeCast device doesn't find custom receiver APP

Tags: android, chromecast

I'm using a custom receiver + using this API (https://github.com/entertailion/DIAL) to connect to Google Cast Device.

This works fine for the sample app TicTacToe, e.g querying `http://MYIP:8008/apps/TicTacToe` I get the status of the service. Also it works fine for Youtube, Netflix, however for my own app I get a 404 when I try to execute a HTTP GET `http://MYIP:8008/apps/APPID`.

I have whitelisted my device + setting the APP ID (according to the new SDK rules, it's composed out of several literals and numerals without any delimiter between them) in my GET query,

From what I can gather it looks like the Google Cast Device doesn't have it's table updated with my own App ID, altough I rebooted the device several times in the past hours.

The WebServer I'm hosting my HTML5 app is an internal server, unknown outside of the network.

How can I make sure that my app will get synched with the my ChromeCast device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DIAL was used in the preview SDK, the official SDK now is not using DIAL anymore, so you should not either; it will not work unless you use the new SDK apis on the sender side as well.

Comment: Then how come previous apps that used DIAL Server still work? Is there some sort of compatibility fallback until the owner of the application uses the new SDK?

Comment: If the owner of the app uses preview SDK, then her/his app will work with the old receiver for a while but if she/he tries to use the new receiver, the sender should use the new APIs as well.

Comment: So if I want for example to stream an application from my Android device to my ChromeCast how would I go about it? Capture the FBO and send it with the current API?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by 'stream' an app from your mobile device to your chromecast. Obviously if it is your own app, there shouldn't be any issue. If it is someone else's app, then there shouldn't be a generic way for you, provided by SDK, to do that; for example the Netflix app owners may not want you to be able to start their app from your app and instead, they may want you to open their own mobile app to use their app on the TV. If they decide to allow others to start their app, they need to provide instructions and such, otherwise, you won't be able to do that.

Comment: By streaming I mean mirroring what I have on the device at that very moment. If I have for example an newspaper aggregator and want to view my it on the TV "mirrored".

Comment: There is no support in the SDK for mirroring.